# Getting value from a text field when button is clicked using aspnet mvc Razor in ext.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, ext.net

I'm having some issues referencing a component to get its value. I have a simple form with a numberfield and a button. To test I just want to output the value of the numberfield when the button is clicked

I have a basic js function

```
var saveNewSats = function (component) {

    console.log(component.getValue());                                   
    };
```

In razor I wire it together like this

```
 X.Button()
 .Text("Save")
 .Listeners(l => l.Click.Handler = "saveNewSats(#{newSatsField});")
```

Where newSatsField is the html id of the numberfield. I tried to reference the field in multiple ways like App.newSatsField, but no luck. What is the correct syntax to get the value from the numberfield?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution.

I did set the InputId which renders the html id attribute. What I needed was to set the ID as this is the one referenced by ext.net. Now both the #{id} and Ext.Cmp syntax works as expected.